# A software father's (un)conditional love for his twin programs

Tags: c#, autohotkey

I have a C# program that fails pretty consistently. That's ok, I've created the program, it is my child, and I love it anyway. As a sort of support, I've decided to write a AutoHotKey wrapper around it, that automatically restarts the program until it finishes without an error. Now, I hope this doesn't make me a terrible father, but there's one more wish I have for the C# program:

If only it could fail without running to Windows 7 for help. The problem is that it requires me to say "Yes close the program, don't debug it." after Windows thinks it can find a solution to the problem.

How can I make the program simply fail without complaint? It has about 5500 more PDFs to consider, and I'll be proud if the twin programs can just sort things out among themselves.

Comment: Seems a bit like the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), what is the reason for the consistent failure?

Comment: This seems like a rather complicated solution. Isn't there a way for you to detect the failure from within the program itself (e.g catching an exception?), and then just retry, rather than using a second program to restart the first?

Comment: Next level down, is there something wrong with the program that causes it to fail? If so, you could fix that.

Comment: @MichaelMadsen Unfortunately, that didn't work. The exception is a AccessViolationException and the only possibility I see is digging into the as-good-as third-party code to look in their AppDomain to intercept the error. The AutoHotKey version works for my one-time purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to have been solved already, but:

[SetErrorMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680621%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) seems able to deactivate the Windows Error Reporting dialog box entirely for your current process. (Tested and works for my artificial access violation.)

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern uint SetErrorMode(uint uMode);    // from msdn page
```

Set uMode to `SEM_NOGPFAULTERRORBOX`, that is `0x0002`.

(btw: Seems you have created a lemming program, so you're a lemming father.)

Comment: I was just kidding. You program is working until there's an access violation, just like in that old lemmings game a lemming is working until it runs in a trap or out of tools and then another lemming (a 'twin') continues the work.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, if there is a module that fails a lot anyway, you could:

- Use [System.Diagnostics.Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) to start it as a separate process.
- Use another [AppDomain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.aspx) (which is in process). If you detect a failure, unload the process.

I would try to solve the problem instead of trying to fight the symptom.

Answer (score 3):

Fixing your child would be preferred path to take but alternatively, you can use following registry keys to disable the prompt

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513638.aspx)

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting]
"ForceQueue"=dword:00000001
"DontShowUI"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\Consent]
"DefaultConsent"=dword:00000002
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll try it out as soon as I've learned how to add the keys to the registry.

Comment: Fortunately, the twin programs finished their job with only a few more incidents. As I expect to let my twins rest in peace from now on, instead of ripping them from the digital afterlife, all I have left to do is thank you again for answering my question.